# How to enable the Raspberry Pi 4 to work remotely?

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, remote-access, raspberry-pi4

Anyone knows how to operate the Raspberry Pi 4 remotely? So that I don't need to always connect it to a monitor when I want to use it.

My Pi is Raspberry Pi 4 with Yocto image built inside. I wonder how to configure the Pi so that it can be used remotely without the need to connect to a monitor. Any helps will be appreciated!

Comment: Run `sudo raspi-config` and do `Enable ssh server`. Then you can connect via the network using `ssh` from a Mac or Linux, or using `Putty` from Windows.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but it shows that sudo: raspi-config: command not found

Comment: I don't know Yocto, but try Googling *"yocto enable ssh server"* and following something new/currrent similar to your environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Yocto reference distro 'Poky', then you can enable one of the following `IMAGE_FEATURE`s:

- `ssh-server-dropbear`  (uses [Dropbear SSH](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html))
- `ssh-server-openssh`  (uses [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/))

and that will start a SSH server at boot.

A quick way to do this, is to add the following to your `local.conf`:

```sh
# local.conf
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "ssh-server-dropbear"
```

A more permanent solution is to define a custom image recipe:

```sh
# my-custom-image.bb
require core-image-minimal.bb

DESCRIPTION = "A small image with a SSH server for remote access"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "ssh-server-dropbear"
```

Alternatively, if you already have your own Yocto configurations - just add either the `dropbear` or `openssh` package to your image/packagegroups.